# Calling ServiceStack internally with URL & JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I have log data consisting of the original request body JSON and path it was received on. When a certain service is triggered I in effect want to run this.

Ie for each url/json object in the log I want to resolve the service and have it handle the request. The API is large and growing so I don't want to have to manually wire up each call.

Is there a way to do this internally? Ie without sending new requests out on the loopback?

Thanks,

Hector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do using ServiceStack's `BasicRequest` which can be plugged into the ServiceStack request pipeline using the `HostContext.ServiceController.Execute` method.

Note this method does not trigger the filters or dependancy injection (You can still resolve from the container in your action method). So this is essentially the same behaviour as MQ requests. So if your requests require to use filters etc, this method of direct service execution may not be suitable for you.

What this does do:

- Parses the provided URL to identify the request DTO type
- Resolves the Service responsible for handling the DTO
- Calls the action method passing in the DTO
- Returns the result from the DTO

Use this method to process the request:

```cs
static object CallInternalService(string path, string method = "GET", string jsonData = null)
{
    // Determine the request dto type based on the rest path
    var restPath = HostContext.ServiceController.GetRestPathForRequest(method, path);
    if(restPath == null || restPath.RequestType == null)
        throw new Exception("No route matched the request"); // Note no fallbacks

    // Create an instance of the dto
    var dto = Activator.CreateInstance(restPath.RequestType);
    if(jsonData != null)
    {
        var data = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(jsonData, restPath.RequestType);
        dto.PopulateWith(data);
    }

    // Create a basic request
    var request = new BasicRequest(dto, RequestAttributes.None);

    // Execute the request
    return HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(dto, request);
}
```

So you simply pass the URL `/Someaction/value` and the method `POST`, along with the JSON data payload:

```cs
var result = CallInternalService("/users/123", "POST", "{\"Name\":\"Bob\",\"Age\":28}");
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Scott, you should be able to use the built-in [ServiceStack.Host.BasicRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/BasicRequest.cs) then execute it with the [ServiceController.Execute()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests/ServiceControllerTests.cs#L71)

Comment: @mythz Thanks, that's brilliant I wasn't aware of that. I am always learning of great things you've already thought of. I've updated to simplify the code.

Comment: np :) fyi, This is the API that all Services are executed with. It's also very close the entry point for MQ requests which is called from within [ServiceController.ExecuteMessage](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8b71560da15823e646ee6c1fb4c96a6fbd9b9efb/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceController.cs#L468).

Answer (score 0):

For [one-way messages the Messaging API](https://twitter.com/demisbellot/status/480080346277752833) is your best option. At the moment there isn't any inter process communication option, such as, named pipes.  However, I did submit a [feature request for named pipes](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/6080039-when-calling-services-on-the-same-server-i-would-l).

Comment: Im not really even after that. I'm after a way of getting from a URL & JSON to the service method which should be called and a de-serialised object to pass it! All of this is internal. Our product has a "record and playback on request" feature, so i'd be calling it from another request service. Any ideas? Thanks